# Where can I find a full Document of Windows EventID explanation

Tags: windows

I've only found Microsoft's explanatory documentation for a single incident so far, where can i find a document includes all event with eventid?

Comment: Anybody can make up new event IDs at any time. There is no document that has "all" of them. It's like asking for a list of "all email addresses".

Comment: so it's a kind of random numbuer?

Comment: No, it's not random. It is well-defined by the event source. But anybody can write an event source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for the [`EVENTLOGRECORD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-eventlogrecord) structure describes the `EventID` field as:

> The event identifier. **The value is specific to the event source for the event**, and is used with source name to locate a description string in the message file for the event source. For more information, see [Event Identifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/EventLog/event-identifiers).

The referenced documentation for [event identifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/eventlog/event-identifiers) goes on to explain:

> Event identifiers uniquely identify a particular event. **Each [event source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/eventlog/event-sources) can define its own numbered events** and the description strings to which they are mapped in its message file.

Since event sources are registered locally on systems, there is no global registry of all event sources. Consequently, with event identifiers being specific to event sources, there cannot be a global registry of all event identifiers. What you are asking for does not exist.

Comment: okay, thx a lot.